# Is it normal for water to collect under the hood?

Tags: nissan, hood

I noticed that some water has collected in a certain area under the hood of a Nissan March 2006. There is water in the same area on the other side as well. Is this normal?

[image: Nissan March 2006 under the hood]

---

I found an image on the internet with a similar engine bay. I have added arrows to show the areas where the water had accumulated.

[image: Full engine bay]

Comment: Have you washed it lately? Are the hood edge seals damaged?

Comment: It's not mine. Assuming the exterior was washed lately, is this normal?

Comment: Answer the second question. But as it is not yours then that may be difficult, do you still have the vehicle to work on?

Comment: Can you add a photo of the full engine bay?

Comment: @HandyHowie Unfortunately, the car is not mine and I did not take a photo of the full engine bay.

Comment: @SolarMike I do not have it unfortunately. If by "hood edge seals" you mean the rubber ones, the car did not have those.

Comment: Usually cars have edge seals. My car does not collect water like that. Unless possibly you went wading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments, it seems that this is not normal.